# How to convert linq query into a datatable

Tags: c#, linq, telerik

I know there are quite a few post on this subject but none of them seem to work for me.

I am trying to convert a linq query into an object that is acceptable for my telerik gridview.

What I have:

```
    var allProjectItems = from x in db.DateItems.AsEnumerable()
      where
        x.Date.ProjectId == projectId
      select new
      {
          ItemDate = (DateTime?)x.Date.ItemDate,
          LastName =
            ((from Users in db.Users
              where
                Users.UserId == x.Date.AddedByUserId
              select new
              {
                  Users.Lastname
              }).FirstOrDefault().Lastname),
          DateItemId = x.DateItemId,
          DateItem1 = x.DateItem1,
          DateValue = x.DateValue,
          DateId = x.DateId,
          DateType = x.DateType
      };
```

I've tried adding .AsEnumerable() onto each table in query but I still am not able to use the query for the gridview or to convert into a datatable with CopyToDataTable method.
Ive also tried to specify requested attributes like x.Field("ProjectId") but Field is not an option.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: how did you try converting it to `DataTable`?

Comment: Is `db.DateItems` a `DataTable` and `x` a `DataRow`?

Comment: what do you mean by "specify requested attributes like x.Field("ProjectId") but Field is not an option." Are you referring to your where clause?

Comment: Also, there is no need to apply `AsEnumerable()` to `db.DateItems`. If you would like to prevent further calls to the db, you can do `allProjectItems.ToList()` before setting the data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting off an anonymous type is going to frustrate you down the road when you actually want to know what object is selected in your gridview.

Just select your DataItem and bind it to your gridview, and set up your Binding on the gridview to show columns for the properties you want to display in the gridview.

```
//Obviously this is simplified and doesn't include your users stuff, but I think you get the idea.

var allProjectItems = (from x in db.DateItems
  where
    x.Date.ProjectId == projectId
  select x).ToList();
```

You will have to set up your bindings on your gridview to show the data you want. As for the user business, I'd set up a partial class on the DataItem that will use navigational properties to get the user and return the values you want.

Comment: For larger tables, it would be better practice to use a DTO. Especially if only a select few of the columns are actually needed.

Comment: Given the apparent use of a LINQ to SQL or EF context in there, adding the additional overhead of DTOs would only add extra overhead and complicate problems further. If size of the data really becomes a problem, then it points to a design, normalization, or querying problem.